# Does django auth supports the same user names?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have two databases and i must move users infor from these to django. The problem is that user names are repeated (these are other users). How does it solve?

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't 'solve' multiple user names - `django.contrib.auth.models.User.username` has `unique=True` so each one must be unique.

The database would solve that problem for you by spitting out a database `IntegrityError` when you try to add a second user with the same username.

If you have a working auth system with multiple usernames, then you're clearly not logging in with the username as a user's unique identifier.

Maybe you're using email addresses for login with the username field as just "flair" (almost like SO) - in which case I might modify the username field to be longer and store the email address in the username field / username in a user profile model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

You could also potentially remove that unique constraint and write your own authentication backend that knows how to find your unique user / check its credentials. There must be /something/ unique about each user, right? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend